# Images not resizing in Chrome, but correctly do in Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I have a row of images that resize correctly in Firefox, but do not resize at all in Chrome.  These images need to stay in a row and cannot fold under each other.

Any suggestions?

```css
.image-rail {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.image-rail img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-rail">

        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">

        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">

        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">

        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the image-rail to display:flex; So that means that the childeren inside that flex can be set with a width that creates the "columns". Your images are the direct childeren of the flexbox. So if you want 4 of them next to each other the all need to be 1/4 of the total width of the flexbox aka 25%.

(Right now you've set a 100% and if you've had used a div it would have been the whole row for each div, but as it is a image the browsers see the 100%, but the images is smaller then the whole row so it sets it to 100% as in all the pixels the image contains.)

```css
.image-rail {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.image-rail img {
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-rail">

        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">

        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">

        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">

        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">

</div>
```

**EDIT: Instead of using a fixed width, auto size your columns based on
the number of elements**

If you want to have all the children of your flexbox to fit in one row, but you're not sure how many children there will be, then you're better of using a gridbox instead of a flexbox.

```css
.image-rail {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    width: 100%;
}

.image-rail img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-rail">
        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">
        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">
        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">
        <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG14.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, of course I forgot that items inside a flex container need a width to work the correct way.  Have any suggestions if the image rail number of images is unknown?  I will have 1-4 images (hopefully not one) but how would you calculate that, is there a way in CSS?

Comment: In my first answer I tried to make sure to make as little as possible changes to your code. But auto-sizing the columns is a valid solution aswell ofcourse. I've included this option with an edit in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
.image-rail {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.image-rail img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or add `flex-wrap: no-wrap` to .image-rail

Comment: that doesn't work still in Chrome.  I didn't add flex-wrap: no-wrap because it's the default for flexbox.

Comment: I tried this with codepen.io and it's works, try this : .image-rail {
    display: flex;
     width:100%;
}
.image-rail img{ 
     width:25%;
}